# Speeding up solution build in Visual Studio Team Services (was VS Online)

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I am using Team Services for my application build/deploy but I am finding that the build step is extremely slow. It ranges in time from 6 minutes to sometimes 15 minutes just for the solution build. A large proportion of this time is taken up by the nuget package restore, which can be up to 5 minutes.

The way I see it there are 2 potential ways in which I could speed up the build time, but I am unsure if it is possible to do these things:

1. Configure Team Services to clone the repository to the same disk location each time it does a build so that it only needs to restore new / remove old nuget packages
2. Upgrade the power of the build agent

Does anyone know if either of these things are possible, or does anyone have any other tips on how to speed up the build step?

Comment: Are you using the Hosted queue?

Comment: Yes I have noticed that the queue is hosted, but when I looked into the pricing etc to maybe upgrade I totally didn't understand the messaging around it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the hosted queue, it has to clone the repo and restore the packages every time -- you don't get a dedicated agent, so every build is from scratch.

You can set up an on-premise build agent if you need capabilities that exceed those of the hosted agent.

Comment: Ok great. I assume setting up an premise agent can be done on an Azure VM easily enough? Can you point me to the queue settings in VS Online as I cannot find them!